# Kestrel with .NET Core - getting SSL_ERROR_PROTOCOL_VERSION_ALERT

Tags: .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I am running a .NET Core application with the following profile in launchSettings.json which should start a Kestrel web server.

```
"MyApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
```

I am running it with `dotnet run --launch-profile "MyApp"`.

When it starts up, I get `SSL_ERROR_PROTOCOL_VERSION_ALERT` in the browser if I visit https://localhost:5001/. HTTP-only at http://localhost:5000/ works fine.

I have tried setting `useSsl = true` and `sslPort = 5001` but the problem remains. It seems that the dev certificate has been properly imported in the browser. I have tried running `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`.

How do I get rid of this error?

**UPDATE**

I found that this only happens when I run/debug the application in Visual Studio Code. In Visual Studio it works perfectly when I launch the application via the debugger.